# How to redirect on specific url - Varnish?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

Sorry, I'm new to **Varnish**.

I'm trying bunch of stuff in my **/etc/varnish/mysite.vlc** but can't make it work.

I want to redirect on specific url to another url. Example:
If someone access `http://mysite1/thepage1.xml` it should go to `http://mysite2/thepage2.xml`

```
varnishd -V
varnishd (varnish-3.0.5 revision 1a89b1f)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Varnish Software AS
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**How to redirect in Varnish 3**

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.url~ "^/thepage1.xml?$") {
    error 750 "http://mysite2/thepage2.xml";
  }
}

sub vcl_error {
  if (obj.status == 750) {
    set obj.http.Location = obj.response;
    set obj.status = 301;
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

**How to redirect in Varnish 4**

```
sub vcl_recv {
  if (req.url~ "^/thepage1.xml?$") {
    return (synth (750, "http://mysite2/thepage2.xml")); #This throws a synthetic page so the request won't go to the backend
  }
}

sub vcl_synth {
  if (resp.status == 750) {
    set resp.http.Location = resp.reason;
    set resp.status = 301;
    return(deliver);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.